# Manage Similar projects on Git

Tags: git

I have these structure that evolved over time.

My main and only project 'POTATO'

we are working on this project, using feature/branches etc and everything works ok.

But we closed a big contract and we agreed to change some things as they wish.

Now POTATO has stuff on branch 'BIG_CLIENT' that only works and make sense for that client

So at this point we have

```
POTATO:master       -> for everyone
POTATO:BIG_CLIENT   -> for BIG_CLIENT
```

The project is going on like this for sometime and things are getting messier in the sense that things might cross over between branches and break when merged.

There are things that only should exist on their respective branches and never should go across,
and there is things that it HAS to exist on both.

For example:

We gonna add an options to order fries potatoes, and it should be equal for both of them.

If I create the branch 'feature/fries' from 'POTATO:master' and merge on 'POTATO:BIG_CLIENT' this will break because things that have on master that should not exist on BIG_CLIENT will be dragged to it, and vice-versa.

I can't figure it out a way to manage that.

If I separate the repositories still will exist the necessity of things exist on both repository....

I don't know if I was clear but let me show a little code example (of course a very silly example, but explain the ideia).

Branch master:

```js
icecream.iceCreamCreator(flavors, typeOfCone)
```

Branch BIG_CLIENT:

```js
if(canIsellIcecreamToThisCustomer){
    icecream.iceCreamCreator(flavors, typeOfCone, clientIsLactoseIntolerant, isTheSkyBlueToday)
    sendSpecialBigClientLogging(customer)
}
```

Now we gonna add the feature 'topping' that have to exist on both.

Each one should became

Branch master:

```js
icecream.iceCreamCreator(flavors, typeOfCone, toppings)
```

Branch BIG_CLIENT:

```js
if(canIsellIcecreamToThisCustomer){
    icecream.iceCreamCreator(flavors, typeOfCone, toppings, clientIsLactoseIntolerant, isTheSkyBlueToday)
    sendSpecialBigClientLogging(customer)
}
```

How to manage something like that?

Comment: My advice, use two repos, and don't use git for dependency management.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you wouldn't want to evolve what is essentially 2 separate codebases by using Git branching alone. As you've already seen that's not scalable and it's just a matter of time when resolving conflicts will start taking more time than writing code.

What you can do instead is refactor (that's going to be big, I'm afraid) your codebase to split out library code and application code. Then you can share the library code between yours and client's projects.

Any code specific to your application goes into repository #1.

Any code specific to your customer application goes into repository #2.

Any shared change/feature goes to the library code (which itself is a 3rd Git repository).

That's one way to tackle it.

Comment: I would also add that the library code should be managed by an actual dependency manager (like npm).

Comment: yes, refactor is on the mind but as you said, it will be a lot of work, I guess that the major part of the codebase is equal, but in some point in the future probably will force us to do what you suggest.
But for now I guess conflicts and copy and paste is the solutions?

Comment: @MateusSilva copy and paste doesn't sound really good. But in the end it's you who knows how many people work on the project, how many existing conflicting changes there are, what's the planned scope of work, etc. It's up to you to decide whether you want to adopt a hacky solution or invest in refactoring.